How do you import an aar library into a flutter plugin?
I'm trying to import a library into a flutter plugin, but the setup is very odd, since you have the android folder and the examples/android folder. Basically I just need to be able to access the library in the android folder. Right now it says it can't find the files. Anyone know of any examples or have thoughts on what i'm doing wrong?
My aar files are in the android/libs folder.
android/build.gradle:
group 'com.mycompany.myplugin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
        namespace 'com.mycompany.myplugin'
    }

    compileSdk 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.0.0'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()

            testLogging {
               events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
               outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
               showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'my-library', ext: 'aar')
}

Error:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find :my-library:.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :myplugin


I figured it out. I needed to add the plugin name to the flat directory and add rootProject in front of allprojects.
group 'com.mycompany.myplugin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs project(':myplugin').file("libs")
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
        namespace 'com.mycompany.myplugin'
    }

    compileSdk 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.0.0'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()

            testLogging {
               events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
               outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
               showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'my-library', ext: 'aar')
}

